# AWS Amplify with Next.js how to access environment variables in api?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

I have an Amplify app (frontend only) serving my Next.js app. In side my /api/ folder I have a file that creates the stripe session to redirect the user to Stripe in order to pay.

In order to create the stripe session, I need to pass to stripe my `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY`, however, if I call it like this:

`const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)`

the API key si not available in my deployed app.

My question is, what is the best practice to have this API key available in my production build?

Comment: Did you setup the `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` environment variable in the Amplify console? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#setting-env-vars.

Comment: as far as I understood those variables are only available during build time, hence not accessible by Next.js backend

Comment: Check out this video. It should also apply to NextJS. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcwfjMebjTU

Answer (score 0):

First I added the `env` variables in the AWS Console (App Settings -> Environment Variables)

Then in the build stage of my app I added the commands to write those variables (which are only available at build time) into a `.env.production` file.
NextJS will pick up the `.env.production` file automatically.

At the end my `amplify.yml` looks like this

```yaml
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - env | grep -e API_URL >> .env.production
        - env | grep -e API_KEY >> .env.production
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
      - '.next/cache/**/*'
```

And in the code I access them as usual doing `process.env.API_URL`